# making my controller code cleaner and less repetitive

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I will post my view and controller below.

I am wondering if there is a better way to do this so I don't need to have the **same code 4 times** over as it is quite a lot to jam up my controller and better practice would be to make it more reusable instead of repeating and changing slight parts.

Here is how it works: the user selects an option, from `FirstName`, `Email` or `PostCode`, and then can select a **timeframe** as shown below. To make this for each would be an easy copy/paste and change but I want to use less code if possible.

Here is my controller statement:

```
//if a user choose the radio button option as FirstName  
if (option == "FirstName")
{ 
    if (date == "day")
    {
        DateTime today = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
        return View(db.Orders.Where(x => x.FirstName.StartsWith(search) && x.OrderDate >= today || search == null).ToList());
    }
    if (date == "week")
    {
        DateTime today = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7);
        return View(db.Orders.Where(x => x.FirstName.StartsWith(search) && x.OrderDate >= today || search == null).ToList());
    }
    if (date == "month")
    {
        DateTime today = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);
        return View(db.Orders.Where(x => x.FirstName.StartsWith(search) && x.OrderDate >= today || search == null).ToList());
    }
    if (date == "year")
    {
        DateTime today = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
        return View(db.Orders.Where(x => x.FirstName.StartsWith(search) && x.OrderDate >= today || search == null).ToList());
    }
    else
    { return View(db.Orders.Where(x => x.FirstName.StartsWith(search) || search == null).ToList());
}
```

My view;

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "EditOrders", FormMethod.Get))
{
    //the following are search options

    <b> Search for: </b>@Html.RadioButton("option", "FirstName") <text>First Name</text> @Html.RadioButton("option", "PostalCode") <text> Post-Code </text>
    @Html.RadioButton("option", "Username")<text>Email-Address</text> @Html.TextBox("search")
    <text>Orders Made </text><select id="date" name="date">
        <option value="none">All Orders</option>
        <option value="day">In the last day</option>
        <option value="week">In the last week</option>
        <option value="month">In the last month</option>
        <option value="year">In the last year</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
}
```

Comment: This goes for Factory pattern implementation; your controller would look simple two lines of code but these conditions would be present in your Factory class which returns necessary object

Comment: one another option is to change your values to actual days; for ex: instead of "day", change it to "1"; instead of "week", change it to "7"; use that value to subtract days in controller

Comment: Use an IQueryable and add each option (firstname, email, postcode, date) separately.  More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22122618/selecting-data-using-entity-framework-based-on-optional-search-parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about changing actual values in the Form

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "EditOrders", FormMethod.Get))
{
    //the following are search options
<b> Search for: </b>@Html.RadioButton("option", "FirstName") <text>First Name</text> @Html.RadioButton("option", "PostalCode") <text> Post-Code </text>
@Html.RadioButton("option", "Username")<text>Email-Address</text> @Html.TextBox("search")
<text>Orders Made </text><select id="date" name="date">
    <option value="0">All Orders</option>
    <option value="1">In the last day</option>
    <option value="7">In the last week</option>
    <option value="30">In the last month</option>
    <option value="365">In the last year</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
}
```

Your Controller code

```
if (option == "FirstName")
{ 
    var days = Convert.ToInt32(date) * -1;

    if(days > 0)
    {
        DateTime today = DateTime.Now.AddDays(days);
        return View(db.Orders.Where(x => x.FirstName.StartsWith(search) && x.OrderDate >= today || search == null).ToList());
    }
    else
    {
         return View(db.Orders.Where(x => x.FirstName.StartsWith(search) || search == null).ToList());
    }
}
```

Comment: 365 would break for a leap year, 30 would break for months (some are 31, others 30, February can have 28 or 29). Also, your else is broken `(search) && || search`

Comment: @user1666620 - that's true; this works only if he is not concerned about that;

Comment: Im testing this now, if it works this would be my preferred method! Not that bothered about leap years etc. Will get back to you in a moment, thanks @techspider

Comment: @techspider thank you very much! This works perfectly and cleans my code up considerably!

Comment: This approach is open to manipulation from the client, if that matters. For example, I could change a date value to 3650 and post the form, and I would see orders for the past 10 years.

Comment: @AndreQueen - you are welcome! you can mark the answer as Solution to close this.

Comment: The best way to solve this problem as specified in my comment on question is to implement a Factory pattern;

Comment: @techspider I don't disagree its not the best method, but for my project and skill level I currently posses this is the best way. Also Ollie P they could if they wanted, it is an admin control which initially allows them to view ALL orders

Answer (score 0):

This is a fine line between what should be on view and what should be on controller, haha.
I vote to clear the code the controller code instead change the view.
You can use a [factory](http://www.dotnetperls.com/factory) pattern, and if you have time, take a look on clean code concepts too. On MVA there are some good lessons.
Again, is personal.

Best!